# Is merely encoding (rather than escaping) for XSS wrong?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, jackson, xss

I've come across this project https://github.com/rwinch/spring-jackson-owasp/blob/master/spring-jackson-owasp-xml.

I was trying to use a particular file from this project for adding Html Escape capability for Jackson's ObjectMapper. But I'm getting the input as the output with no changes. Seems like the following code from that project is not doing any encoding.

```
public class OwaspCharacterEscapes extends CharacterEscapes {
private final int[] ESCAPES;

public OwaspCharacterEscapes() {
    ESCAPES = standardAsciiEscapesForJSON();
    for(int i=0;i<ESCAPES.length;i++) {
        if(!(Character.isAlphabetic(i) || Character.isDigit(i))) {
            ESCAPES[i] = CharacterEscapes.ESCAPE_CUSTOM;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public SerializableString getEscapeSequence(int ch) {
    **String unicode = String.format("\\u%04x", ch);
    return new SerializedString(unicode);**
}

@Override
public int[] getEscapeCodesForAscii() {
    return ESCAPES;
}

private static final long serialVersionUID = 8140493311454723880L;
```

}

In the `getEscapeSequence` method, there is only a mere conversion from `int ch` to `string`. I changed that code as following, then it's working.

```
new SerializedString(StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(Character.toString((char) ch)));
```

I found that project from a spring's documentation somewhere. So I wouldn't want to believe that there is something wrong in it, am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The highlighted part of the original code you presented converts the code point for a character of the Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane into a JavaScript Unicode escape sequence (string) representing the same character.  The code is a bit suspect because it handles code points outside the BMP incorrectly, but it may be that the project from which it is drawn addresses that outside the scope of the class presented.

Unicode escape sequences have the same meaning to JavaScript (and JSON) as the corresponding Unicode characters, so translating from one form to the other does not alter the semantics of a piece of JavaScript in any way.  The point of performing such a conversion is to support transfering JavaScript code (and / or JSON data) via a text format that does not encode all of Unicode, such as text encoded in any of the ISO-8859 family of encodings.  Since semantics are unchanged by the transformation, this has no bearing on XSS.

In any event, the Unicode escape sequences you can obtain via the code you present are not HTML character entities.  If you want to perform perform HTML escaping, such as replacing `<` with `&lt;`, then that's an altogether different thing, serving altogether different purposes.

Comment: I think this is with respect to Javascript Encoding section in the table, https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Output_Encoding_Rules_Summary, as vaguely mentioned in https://github.com/rwinch/spring-jackson-owasp/blob/master/spring-jackson-owasp-xml/README.adoc, but I'm not sure what it achieves with respect to XSS, I used that class, and alert() message is displayed since as you said it's merely encoding with unicode.

Comment: Seems like I need to first escape then encode, which might pretty inefficient and makes the whole data large.

Comment: @pinkpanther, as I said, it achieves *nothing* with respect to XSS.  JavaScript code in which some characters have been transformed according to that method has exactly the same behavior as the un-transformed code.  That's central to its purpose.

Comment: @pinkpanther, If you're going to apply HTML escapes to the code in any case, then I'm not seeing what advantage would be gained by also performing Unicode escapes ala the method presented.